# changing several background images

Tags: jquery

Hi i'm currently trying to tidy up some of my code i have:

```
    $('#b1').css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/1.png")');
    $('#b2').css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/2.png")');
    $('#b3').css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/3.png")');
    $('#b4').css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/4.png")');
    $('#b5').css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/5.png")');
    $('#b6').css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/6.png")');
    $('#b7').css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/7.png")');
```

It works perfectly fine, but would like to know if there is any better options available or methods?

Comment: loop i with this, $('#b' + i).css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/' + i + '.png")');

Comment: BTW what is this #b1 is, is it div or what? give them a class and iterate on basis of it

Comment: yes its a div, Loop? okay thanks ill have a look into it :)

Comment: loop means iterate ;)

Comment: Thanks Everyone its great to get loads of different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigh a class (say `images`) to all the `b1,b2,b3`.. etc

Then:

```
$(".images").each(function(){
   $(this).css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/" + this.id.replace("b","") + ".png")');
});
```

Comment: Yup, although I posted an answer below, this seems to be the better solution - voting it up!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
var i;
for ( i = 1; i <= 7; i++ ) {
  $('#b' + i).css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/' + i + '.png")');
}
```

Comment: I disagree with you my frnd as this would be a very hard coded rough code, this can be a workaround not good way of solving it.

Comment: Absolutely. Unfortunately there aren't enough details to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=1; i<=7; i++){
 $('#b'+i).css('background-image', 'url("site_images/05/'+i+'.png")');
}
```

Note that this frees up the variable `i` if you are using it somewhere else in the code - the scope gets local to just the for loop

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

If these elements have a parent element you could simply use CSS and add a specific class to the parent element.

```
html.bg_switched #bg1 { 
    background-image: url("site_images/05/1.png");
}

html.bg_switched #bg2 { 
    background-image: url("site_images/05/2.png");
}
...
```

Then:

```
$('html').addClass('bg_switched');
```

Or something to this extent.